Attaching to a running Java process for debugging
I am running VSCode on Fedora Linux.  I have the following extensions installed:
Debugger for Java,
Extension Pack for Java
I added the following launch.json:
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "processId": "${command:PickJavaProcess}"
    }
    ]
}

However, I do not see a menu option for "Attach by Process ID" under the Run menu.  How can I make the attach option show?
(I know I have the Java process set up correctly because I attach to it with intellij all of the time.)
Thanks!

Apparently, adding a launch configuration doesn't update the run menu as I assumed.  When you click the "Run and Debug" icon, you see the launch option there.  Pretty unintuitive if you ask me.
